# Accesing the webelements in the webview of andropid using robotium 4.1

Tags: webview, robotium

I am trying to open "`https://www.google.co.in/`" in android `webview`. Now I want to search something so I want to put the text in the edit text of the `google.co.in` page in the web view. Is it possible using `robotium 4.1` and how?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes it is possible using robotium 4.1. As robotium 4.1 has a support for web view.

By this line

**WebView object = (WebView) getActivity().findViewById((package name).R.id.(Webview ID));**

we can get the object of web view and we can use it.

And 
**solo.typeTextInWebElement(By.tagName("tag name"),"Text");**

By this line we can click on the web elements we want. And tag name is like different tags in the web elements like body, html,input etc